# why do my titles always have extra space below the letters?

Tags: html, css

This is something I have always wondered. For some reason this happens a lot, and I don't know why. I usually just end up giving the element a height and a line height in order to center the text inside of its little box.

This is the code I have:

```
<h3 class="hr_title">Things to know before</h3>
```

Then this is the css for it.

```
.hr_title{
   background-color: navy;
   color: white;
   font-family:proxima-nova, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
}
```

Below is a photo of how it looks.

[image]

Forgot to mention. This happens even if I add text-transform:uppercase or if they are all capital letters.

Comment: Because of the letter "g" in "things to know"

Comment: Forgot to mention. This happens even if I add text-transform:uppercase or if they are all capital letters.

Comment: Check Ouroborus' answer as he's addressed everything you've said. Easiest way I've found to keep that from driving you mad is to add padding to the top and bottom (not much, usually like 5px or so). This way it looks more deliberate that there was spacing there.

Answer (score 3):

It's for letters that have descenders such as `g` or `j`. Even if you aren't using letters with descenders (such as all caps), it's still part of the character metrics.

---

`text-transform:uppercase` just changes the casing of the letters. It doesn't do anything with the character metrics. For example, it doesn't remove the portion of the character layout that would hold the descenders.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out that is caused by [Ascender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)) and [Descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)). See also this nice picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

Here you can see it again in practice:

```css
h3 {
   background-color: navy;
   color: white;
   font-family:proxima-nova, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 100;
   font-size:5em;
}
```

```html
<h3>TEST gg Â</h3>
```

Comment: so there is no way to make the ascender height and descender height the same right?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You could try to correct it yourself, however I think it is not worth to try it.

Comment: However if you would like to try it `padding-top:0.01em;` might help you. You can play with the value.

Answer (score -2):

There are also default margins baked into some element tags. If you're not using a css reset or normalize snippet, then it will effect it.

`margin: 0; padding: 0;` will fix it